# How to do concept art without knowing how to draw?

Tags: art, hand-drawn

I want to do some art's of my upcoming game, but dont really know how to draw. Wich program can I use, or should I draw it on paper? Just give me tips on how to do it.

Comment: If you're trying to make a graphical game, you're going to need an artist. Either you become an artist, or you recruit one.

 For becoming an artist, you can search for any number of resources on the web, from 3D art to impressionist painting to whatever else you fancy. You could also visit your local college and take some introductory art classes to see if art is your thing.

 Otherwise, you can find a friend who is an artist, or hire someone who is an artist, describe what you're looking for, and let your friend/hire take it from there.

Comment: Or you can just use freeware art assets which are plenty on the web and Unity Store.

Comment: Building on what @MichaelS said: even if it's a friend, you should still hire them. Asking artists to devote their time and energy to something without pay is kind of a mean thing to do, even/especially if they're your friend. And no, "I'll pay you when the game sells" doesn't cut it, because many many game projects never turn a profit.

Comment: Well... why don't you draw "as you can" and keep working on rest of game, just using "not really nice art"? I'm doing it all the time :3